# Assign many fields at once in derived class - why does this work?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I wanted a constructor of derived class to be able to assign some data from an object being this constructor's argument, while class of argument is parent class of constructed object itself.

This code is working. But I wonder whether this is correct or I am just being lucky and should expect crash in different runtime conditions. How does C++ calculate valid addresses of `Args` fields during copying, since compiler does not know whether this is "standalone" `Args` object or part of larger object? How does `dynamic_cast` actually work here, since objects are not polymorphic?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base {
    int FieldBInt;
    double FieldBDouble;
    Base () : FieldBInt(10), FieldBDouble(13.5) { }
};

struct Args {
    int FieldAInt;
    string FieldAString;
};

struct Derived : public Base, public Args {
    int FieldDInt;
    double FieldDDouble;
    explicit Derived (const Args & args) : Base(), FieldDInt(40), FieldDDouble(14.5) {
        Args * castedThis = dynamic_cast<Args *>(this);
        *castedThis = args;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Derived d ({50, "Text"});
    cout << d.FieldBInt << " " << d.FieldBDouble << endl
         << d.FieldAInt << " " << d.FieldAString << endl
         << d.FieldDInt << " " << d.FieldDDouble << endl;
}
```

Code prints (correctly):

```
10 13.5
50 Text
40 14.5
```

Comment: You can add `Args(args)` to the initializer list instead of casting and assigning.

Comment: "Safe or heading for a crash"?! Those aren't opposites -- do you mean "correct"? "Safe" is a totally meaningless word.

Comment: Wow! Silly me :-) of course I can since it's simply calling base constructor. :-) Anyway I am still interested in original question.

Comment: Yes it does actually compile...

Comment: Forgive poor choice of words: "safe" as in "it is working because it's correct, not because I had some luck by chance".

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: I'd still just call that "correct", because the opposite is plain "incorrect", current appearances of "working" notwithstanding. Yes, sorry, it does compile, I was confused by the weird dynamic cast.

Comment: The version without the cast crashes because `*this = *(&args);` is the same here as `*this = Derived(args)`, which causes infinite recursion.

Comment: You can stop writing `*(&args)`, it is the same as `args`

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks. I was just experimenting different syntax.

Comment: @interjay, you are right, I've added `explicit` to constructor and it stopped compiling.

Comment: Thank you for all useful comments. I still wonder about how `dynamic_cast` works in this scenario. I edited the question accordingly. Also please remove downvote or explain why this is not a valid question.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is the same as `static_cast` here. If you are in a `Derived` then you can always get to the `Base`.  The dynamic is different when you are in a `Base` because then you do not know if you are part of a larger `Derived`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived class uses multiple inheritance to inherit from Base and from Args class.
With `Args * castedThis = dynamic_cast<Args *>(this);` you get a pointer to the Args part of d.

It could be expected that Derived object d starts with a it's Base part followed by it's Args part followed by its own members. I don't know if its required someway by the standandard or not.

In any case `dynamic_cast<Base *>(this)` and `dynamic_cast<Args *>(this)` will give you different adresses.

`*castedThis = *(&args);` will cause a copy assignment operator for struct Args to be generated. This copy assignment operator will copy Args members.

When you initialize Args in the initializer list as other users suggested you are generating and using a copy constructor instead of a copy assignment operator.

In your code the Arg part of d is first default initialized and then copy assigned.

Of course it will be much clearer to initialize base members in initializer list as people suggested.

**Edit to answer: How does dynamic_cast actually work here, since objects are not polymorphic?**

In this case [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) will work here because both will work as **conversion casts**, they will **convert** a pointer. With static_cast the check to see if it can be converted will be done at compile time, with dynamic_cast it will be done at runtime (with no benefit in this case).

Reading from cppreference I think a [C-Style cast or explicit cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) will work too because it seems it should work as an [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

So this case polymorphism (runtime polymorphism) has nothing to do. Type-checking and converting at compile time or at runtime will do the same.

Note: The code `*this = *(&args);` that you put in the original edit of the question gives me the following compiler error: *no match for 'operator='(operand types are 'Derived' and 'const Args')*. That code calls an asignment operator that can assign a value to a Derived object from an Args object and we have not defined any function to do that.

Comment: I think this: "In any case dynamic_cast<Base *>(this) and dynamic_cast<Args *>(this) will give you different adresses." is essential for me to understand. Indeed, I had printed both addresses to console and they differ in expected 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> since compiler does not know whether this is "standalone" Args object
>   or part of larger object?

You inherited from it directly. The compiler clearly knows. In fact, the Standard defines `dynamic_cast` to be equal to `static_cast` in this case, which is pretty much equivalent to just `Args* castedThis = this;`.